# Appirater doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, review, appirater

I'd like to show Appirater when I click some button.
here is my setting in appdelegate

```
Appirater.setAppId("...")
Appirater.setDaysUntilPrompt(0)
Appirater.setUsesUntilPrompt(0)
Appirater.setTimeBeforeReminding(30)
Appirater.setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt(10)
Appirater.userDidSignificantEvent(true))
Appirater.appLaunched(true)
```

and then I put below code in my view controller

`Appirater.tryToShowPrompt()`

I don't any idea how to call correct method in action.

Comment: It might be unable to show the prompt. Did you try to use `forceShowPrompt` method?

Comment: @ridvankucuk oh! It's work now thanks a lot!

Comment: I have added an answer. If it helped you, you can accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to use `forceShowPrompt` method. However by forcing the prompt consider the side effects. By the way if you want to see the Appirater on the debug mode always, you can use `Appirater.setDebug(true)` method.